# From $1$ to $50$, take a pair of integers so that their sum is greater than $50$

Tags: combinatorics

From $1$ to $50$, take a pair of integers (repetition allowed) so that their sum is greater than $50$ , how many ways are there pick such pair?

Attempt:

1st number = $50$ , 2nd number ($1$ to $50$) - $50$ combinations

1st number = $49$, 2nd number ($2$ to $49$) - $49$ combinations

.

.

.

1st number number = $1$ , 2nd number $50$ - $1$ combination

Summation of $1$ to $50 = 1275$

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: Your attempt is correct if you assume that the order within the pair matters.  If you consider $1+50$ to be the same result as $50+1$ then you'll need to be a bit more careful.

Comment: Does the order in which you pick the numbers matter?  For example is 1 then 50 the same as 50 then 1?

Comment: How do I solve for it considering that 1 + 50 and 50 +1 are the same?

Comment: "How do I solve for it considering that 1 + 50 and 50 +1 are the same?"  Divide in half.  Then realize that that can't be the answer because it's a fraction.  Think about it and then realize that because $a=b$ was only counted once.  So if $a=b$ there are $25$ ways to do those ($a=26,26,27,...,50$) so subtract $25$ frome $1275$ to get $1250$ ways where $a \ne b$.  Divide by 2 to that $625$ ways that $a + b = b+a > 50;a\ne b$. And add the $25$ back to get $650$ ways that $a + b = b+a .>50$ and $a$ may or may not equal $b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say 'pair', I am sure the order does not matter. So, you are double-counting many pairs. How many? Well, pretty much all of them, except the ones where the two numbers are the same.

Since you have $25$ pairs with the same number - namely $(26,26)$ through $(50,50)$ - that means you have $1275-25=1250$ ordered pairs with two different numbers, and hence only $\frac{1250}{2}=625$ unordered pairs.

Total: $625+25=650$ unordered pairs

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, but only if you have to verify this fact: Repetition means choosing the same two numbers is allowed, does it mean that you can choose the same pair, swapped positions as well? (For example, $50$ and $1$, $1$ and 50). If the same pair, swapped positions is not allowed then the answer must be reduced:

Assume that the first number is always less than or equal the second number.

1st number = $1$; 2nd number = $50$ - $1$ combination

1st number = $2$; 2nd number ($49$ to $50$) - $2$ combinations

.

.

1st number = $24$; 2nd number ($27$ to $50$) - $24$ combinations

1st number = $25$; 2nd number ($26$ to $50$) - $25$ combinations

1st number = $26$; 2nd number ($26$ to $50$) - $25$ combinations

1st number = $27$; 2nd number ($27$ to $50$) - $24$ combinations

1st number = $28$; 2nd number ($28$ to $50$) - $23$ combinations

1st number = $29$; 2nd number ($29$ to $50$) - $22$ combinations

.

.

1st number = $49$; 2nd number ($49$ to $50$) - $2$ combinations

1st number = $50$; 2nd number = $50$ - $1$ combination

If the same pair, swapped positions is not allowed:

$(1+2+3+...+50)\times 2=650$ combinations